# Modified .bash_profile and now I can't even use ls

Tags: macos, bash

I just added a few paths to `/Users/userA/.bash_profile` and sourced it.

It seemed to work, I could access more programs. Now I can't even access `ls`.
Only `cd` and `source` are still working.

What do I need to do to restore my settings?
I removed the changes to `.bash_profile` using TextEdit, and sourced again but still no luck using `ls` or `cd`.

Update: For users reading this the cause of this problem was in my case failing to ad $PATH to the end of profile entries 
for example:

```
 PATH=$HOME/downloads/atlassian-jira-5.1-standalone:$PATH
```

If you leave out :$PATH at the end and save you can have this problem.

Comment: I wonder if you've identified the correct root cause: 'cd' is a shell built-in, so if that's failing then your problem is unlikely to be an issue with your path.  What exactly happens when you try to 'cd' into a known-good directory?

Comment: Ok. When I opened a new window after sourcing the modified file using TextEdit it seemed to work.  just forgot to add $PATH to the end of my last entry in the file!

Comment: Feel free to answer your question yourself. Answers are best posted as an actual answer, and not as part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that the issue really is a path problem, the default Mac OS X path (on 10.7) appears to be:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

So you can set this by running

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I actually ran into this problem a second time.

Comment: For users reading this, its very easy to have this problem when you edit .bash_profile by FAILING to add $PATH at the end of your entries export PATH=$HOME/downloads/atlassian-jira-5.1-standalone:$PATH

Comment: good thing export is still working...

Answer (score 2):

`export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`.  Then be more careful adding stuff to `$PATH` in the future; as you've just discovered, the wrong change makes external commands difficult to access.

(You can still get to them by full pathname, by the way; most are in `/usr/bin`.)